# Getting 404 on post request for Lemon squeezy Integration in a Laravel app

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I recently integrated Lemon Squeezy into my Laravel app. I followed all the instructions provided in the documentation, and my webhooks are successfully being registered and sent to Lemon Squeezy. According to the documentation, webhooks should update the database automatically. However, I am encountering a 404 error on post requests. Despite this, when I check my Lemon Squeezy account, I can see the records, but they are not reflected in my local database.

.

I have tried to follow the documentation given by lemon squeezy and was expecting to see my local db being updated by webhooks so that my billable users can checkout and do stuffs associated with them.

Comment: hello, i would update the question with some more info, like are you using packages to handle lemon squeezy, about the route that gives 404 error can you see it in the list of your routes?

Comment: Yes I checked the list of routes and its there ,I  never added it manually though, so its seems the package does a lot of things behind the seen. @suxgri

Comment: i don t have much to say just make sure the routes match and then test manually as explained there https://docs.lemonsqueezy.com/help/webhooks

Comment: I have done all written here ,You seems to understand this so well, can you assist me beyond here may be a meeting ,mathewsagumbah@gmail.com ,@suxgri

Comment: The events are being sent and i can see them in my lemon squeezy account as explained in the documentation above. My bigger problem is why am getting 404 and  my db are not updating, there might be some slight misconfiguration somewhere .

Comment: 404    POST   /lemon-squeezy/webhook ........................................... 22:50:05    7 ms